# Discontinuous power series at radius 1

Tags: continuity, power-series

How to show that the power series 
$$
f(z) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{3^{n}}-z^{2\cdot 3^{n}}}{n}
$$ 
is discontinuous at $z=1$?
I already know the series diverges to $-\infty$ for $z=e^{i\pi / 3^{k}}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and I tried showing that $f(z)<-M$ for any positive number $M$, if $z$ is sufficiently close to $e^{i\pi / 3^{k}}$, but I didn't succeed in proving it in any rigorous manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z=e^{\pi i\cdot 3^{-k}}$ and $n\ge k$, $\frac{z^{3^{n}}-z^{2\cdot 3^{n}}}{n}=\frac{e^{\pi i\cdot 3^{n-k}}-e^{2\pi i\cdot 3^{n-k}}}{n}=-\frac{2}{n}$, then $f(z)=C-\sum\limits_{n\ge k}\frac{2}{n}=-\infty$.

This power series
$ \sum _{n>0}{\frac {z^{3^{n}}-z^{2\cdot 3^{n}}}{n}}$
converges to $0$ at $z=1$, but is unbounded at any point of the form $ e^{\pi i/3^{n}}$, so the value at $z=1$ is not the limit as $z=e^{\pi i/3^{n}}$ tends to 1 in the whole open disk. You can see it [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: Can you show it's unbounded near $e^{\pi i/3^{n}}$?

Comment: @rulergraham I think it may be bounded near $e^{\pi i\cdot 3^{-k}}$, for example ,$\{z_m=e^{\pi i\cdot (3^{-k}+3^{-m})}\}$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$ enough large, $f(z_m)=0$.

Comment: So why isn't $f(z)$ continuous at $1$?

Comment: @rulergraham In fact, $f(z)$ is bounded in some sequence towards $p_k=e^{\pi \cdot 3^{-k}}$ and is also unbounded  in some sequence towards $p_k$ within the open disk, such as $\{z_m'=p_ke^{-\frac{1}{m}}\}$ (since $f(p_k)=-\infty$, for any $M>0$ there exists $n_0$ enough large s.t. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n_0} \frac{{p_k}^{3^n}-{p_k}^{2\cdot 3^n}}{n}<-M$, then there exists ${m_0}$ enough large s.t. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n_0} \frac{{z_m'}^{3^n}-{z_m'}^{2\cdot 3^n}}{n}<-M$ for $m\ge m_0$ from its continuity).

Comment: For any $M>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we can choose such $z_{k,m_k}$ near $p_k$ in the open disk, s.t. $f(z_{k,m_k})<\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n_{k,0}}\frac{z_{k,m_k}^{3^n}-z_{k,m_k}^{2\cdot 3^n}}{n}<-M$. Then the sequence $\{z_{k,m_k}\}$ tends $z=1$ in the open disk, s.t. $f(z_{k,m_k}<-M$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, but $f(1)=0$. Hence, $f(z)$ is discontinuous at 1.